# Progress of data transfer from SQL Server to Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have to transfer a table from SQL Server to Oracle.

The data is "pushed" from SQL Server to Oracle and this cannot be changed, unfortunately.

So, I successfully set up a linked server in SQL Server which points to Oracle.

The transfer is done like this

```
INSERT INTO OPENQUERY([ORACLE_SERVER], 'select <columns> FROM OracleTable')
    SELECT <column> 
    FROM SqlTable
```

I have some 200k rows to transfer.

Usually it takes about 10 minutes, which is fine. But sometimes the process takes more than an hour.

Is there a way to see the transfer progress, using monitoring tools on SQL Server or on Oracle?

I can change the code to transfer chunks of data, but that's not an option on short term :(.

Comment: If you use `SSIS - Data Flow Task` it shows how many rows are processed. Not sure about linked server.

Comment: Linked servers execute queries. Queries don't report progress. This is an ETL job though, not a simple query. If you want to perform ETL jobs though SSIS is a LOT better and faster. With SSIS you can control buffering, transactions and locking both on the source and target. You can't do that with OPENQUERY or a linked server.